# How to bypass the Super class constructor parameters

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, super, superclass

I have just started out leaning about abstract class.

I came across this abstract class question that I saw from some coding test. Already, I am stumped by the way of how the object `Wagon` is initiated.

As seen in the `Vehicle` abstract class, its constructors only holds two parameters - `isSedan` and `seats`

One of the requirements is to create the `Wagon` class. However, as seen in the main (provided by the question), the `Wagon` object is instead initiated with `new Wagon(1000)` in which the `isSedan` and seats values are missing.

I tried writing my wagon class, however, I am unable to bypass `super` parameters of `isSedan` and `seats` without changing the given context in the main class. I tried to google for more info, but was unable to find any answers.

Can someone kindly enlighten me?

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    protected boolean isSedan;
    protected String seats;

    public Vehicle(boolean isSedan, String seats) {
        this.isSedan = isSedan;
        this.seats = seats;
    }
}

class Wagon extends Vehicle {
    public Wagon(boolean isSedan, String seats) {
      super(isSedan, seats);
    }

    // I need to write out both the super params and the mileage params, however this will not work too    
    // public Wagon(boolean isSedan, String seats, int mileage) {
    //   super(isSedan, seats);
    //   this.mileage = mileage;
    // }    
    // public Wagon(int mileage) {
    //   this.mileage = mileage;
    // }
    // public int getMileage() {
    //   return this.mileage;
    // }
}

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    // 1000 is the mileage
    Wagon w = new Wagon(1000);
  } 
}
```

Comment: What is `new Wagon(1000)` meant to be doing? create a `Vehicle` that is not a sedan and has 1000 seats? Or, based on code comment, create a Vehicle that is not a sedan and has 2 seats (just a guess) and somehow we also need to store the mileage?

Comment: Anyway you can pass any argument to the `super` call as with any method (e.g. `super(false, seats);` or `super(true, 2);`) ((`super` must just be the first statement of the constructor)) || answering the question: you cannot bypass it

Answer (score 0):

A call to the constructor of the *super class* `super()` has to be present, either explicitly or implicitly, as the first line of a constructor in the *subclass*. I.e. every time an instance of a *subclass* is being created, under the hood an object of its *parent class* will be instantiated, and the parent of its parent, and so on all the way up to the `Object` class.

***Note**: in the case when a constructor of the subclass is calling another overloaded constructor with the key word* `this()`, *the call* `super()` *needs to be present only in the last constructor called using* `this()`.

In this case, parent class `Vehicle` declares only one constructor, which expects two arguments. That means that *no-argument* constructor will not be generated by the compiler. And as a consequence, the compiler will not be able to add an implicit call `super()` to constructor of the `Wagon` class.

I.e. the call to the constructor of `Vehicle` class need to added explicitly, and you need to pass exactly two arguments as it expects. There's ***no way to bypass it***.

There's nothing specific to `abstract` classes, that's so-called *constructor chain* works in Java.

However, there is nothing wrong with *constructor* of the *child class* that take different number of arguments than constructor of the *parent* which it calls.

You can implement the constructor of `Wagon` that takes only the number of sits by passing `true` to the constructor of parent:

```
public Wagon(String seats) {
    super(true, seats);
}
```

I guess this constructor was accidentally omitted in the code you've come across with.

Comment: @user16320675 Sure, in the case when constructor of the subclass is calling another overloaded constructor, the call `super()` needs to be present only in the last constructor called using `this()`. I intended to give only a general idea of how *constructor chain* works without diving into details because this question isn't dedicated to the usage of `super()` and `this()`.

Comment: @user16320675 Added description of this case to the answer